# Tables aren't responsive in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have code to generate a table:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Friendly Name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Unique Tracker URL</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">URL Endpoint</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1">Bitly Link</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1">Info and Settings</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1">Danger Zone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="linksBody">
        <tr id="links">
            <td>(<a onclick="edit(this)">Edit</a>) <?php echo $row['friendly']; ?></td>
            <td>(<a onclick="editEnd(this)">Customize</a>) <a href="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $row['endpoint']; ?>"><?php echo $row['endpoint']; ?></a></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $row['bitly']; ?>"><?php echo $row['bitly']; ?></a></td>
            <td><a onclick="showDetails(this);">Show</a>/<a onclick="settings(this);">Settings</a></td>
            <td><a onclick="del(this);">Delete</a>/<a onclick="reset(this);">Reset</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It scales well until about 1275px wide, as seen below:

[image]

However, when the screen size goes below that, it starts breaking:

[image]

What can I do to make my table responsive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap has a class for this: `.table-responsive`.
You can read all about his [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive).

Wrap your code in a div with this class. Example:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        [...]
    </table>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: Wow, it really is that easy. For anyone else looking, I had to warp my table in a div and apply the `table-responsive` class to my div but it worked after that.

Comment: Sometimes the problems that seem the toughest have the easiest solutions, glad to see that it worked! @Chipperyman